# Call an Objective-C function from C++ library code

Tags: ios, cocos2d-x

I'd like to call a Obj-C function from my C++ code, in order to invoke a ShareKit call from a game engine.

How do I perform the Obj-C function call?

I'm using Cocos2d-x.

Comment: Create a .mpp file to contain the "glue" code.  Code a C++ function that then uses Objective-C syntax to do call the target function.

Comment: I think "mpp" is about the only extension that's not valid for ObjC++. I recommend ".mm", though theoretically you could also use ".M" (that must be an uppercase "M").

Comment: IIRC if you change to `.mm` don't you then lose the ability to compile those source files on Win, Linux, etc?

Comment: can someone please provide small example of it? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Objective-C++.  To do that, you make a C++ file with the extension “.mm”.  Within that file, both Objective-C and C++ syntax are valid, so you can `#import` your Objective-C headers and send messages using the `[]` syntax.