# Call native ObjC classes from cocos2d-x code

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-x

How can I call/bridge my native iOS ObjC classes from cocos2d-x C++?
Using cocos2d-x 3.5.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24636264/call-an-objective-c-function-from-c-library-code?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Use Objective-C to C++ callbacks

http://www.plungeinteractive.com/blog/2012/08/05/obj-c-to-cpp-callbacks/

Edit:

```
//
//  iOSHelper.h
//

#ifndef __iOSHelper__
#define __iOSHelper__

#include <iostream>

class iOSHelper
{
public:
    void showAlert();
};
#endif
```

-

```
//
//  iOSHelper.mm
//

#include "iOSHelper.h"
//--
#import "AppController.h"

void iOSHelper::showAlert()
{
    AppController* appController = (AppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [appController showAlert];
}
```

Comment: They write about the other way around, but looks promising.