# How to load/show OS-specific activity / view from a Cocos2d-x Scene?

Tags: cocos2d-x

I have a cocos2d-x game from which I would like to show an Activity (if the user is using Android) and a ViewController (if the user is using iOS) and then when the user dismisses these views I return to the Cocos2d-x scene that they are in.

Does anyone know of a strategy I could take to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The native views have to be called by native code. 
iOS is Objective-c, Android is Java.

The links here should give you some concepts.

- For android : http://stnguyen.com/cocos2d-x/call-java-functions-from-cpp.html
- For iOS     : [Call native ObjC classes from cocos2d-x code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449900/call-native-objc-classes-from-cocos2d-x-code)